# doc with multi-field of boolean type fails during creation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

In v5.5, we had the following mapping which was working fine

```
PUT multiple_datatypes
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "user_data": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "numeric": {
              "type": "double",
              "ignore_malformed": true
            },
            "date": {
              "type": "date",
              "ignore_malformed": true
            }
            "logical": {
              "type": "boolean",
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In 6.2, the same mapping fails with the error
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]\n{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"failed to parse [user_data.logical]\"}],\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"failed to parse [user_data.logical]\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Failed to parse value [auto_directorUrl] as only [true] or [false] are allowed

The input data was a string, "auto_directorURL" and it failed. The ignore_malformed flag is not available for boolean types. However, this worked in v5.5. I find that in v6.2, ES has strictly enforced boolean type values as 'true' or 'false'. but this fails in multi-fields as it does not have a ignore_malformed flag.
what is the solution for this? Is this a BWC break and a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an [announced breaking change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-6.0.html#_coercion_of_boolean_fields).

An alternative would be to use an [ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) with a [convert processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html) to store the booleanized value of that field into another boolean field:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/boolean-pipeline
{
  "description": "converts the content of the field to a boolean value",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "user_data",
        "target_field" : "user_data_boolean",
        "type": "boolean",
        "on_failure" : [
          {
            "set" : {
              "field" : "user_data_boolean",
              "value" : false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can index data using that pipeline

```
PUT test/doc/1?pipeline=boolean-pipeline
{
  "user_data": "true"
}

PUT test/doc/2?pipeline=boolean-pipeline
{
  "user_data": "auto_directorURL"
}
```

As a result you'd get the following indexed data, which is pretty much what you'd expect:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user_data" : "auto_directorURL",
      "user_data_boolean" : false
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "user_data" : "true",
      "user_data_boolean" : true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This solution does not work for the mapping I have given. The mapping contains multi-fields. The example above is for a new field. In my case, I tried setting, user_data.logical, on failure but this is not accepted by ES. It complains about setting a boolean value for a text type (user_data is defined as text)

Comment: You need to forget about `user_data.logical` and remove it as you cannot set that field. You need to create another top-level field named `user_data_boolean` or something like that.